# Xero SDK - OAuth implementation of state parameter

Tags: node.js, xero-api

I have currently implemented a NodeJs, express api with the `xero-node` sdk package, and I've run into an issue where it doesn't seem that the OAuth state parameter is not being used (though I see it is defined as an optional parameter for the XeroClient constructor:

```
export interface IXeroClientConfig {
  clientId: string,
  clientSecret: string,
  redirectUris: string[],
  scopes: string[],
  state?: string
}
```

Can anyone confirm if this has been implemented yet?

I am assuming it would work like this:

```
const xero = new XeroClient({
  clientId: xeroParams.clientId,
  clientSecret: xeroParams.clientSecret,
  redirectUris: [xeroParams.redirectUrl],
  scopes: xeroParams.scopes.split(' '),
  state: this.callback_state,
});

//then when building the consent url like this, the state param would be included
const consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl();
```

And then when the callback gets triggered I was expecting to be able to access the `state code` as one of the query params. Something along the lines explained [here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow)

I have seen the `session_state` parameter being returned but this is not matching the state code I supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you pass state through the OAuth flow using the `xero-node` SDK:

> https://github.com/SerKnight/xero-node-basic-app/blob/master/index.js#L37

Example:

- first generate the consentUrl, then append your custom params.

```js
app.get('/connect', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    let consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl();
    res.redirect(consentUrl + "&state=THIS_IS_A_STANDARD_OAUTH_2_STATE_PARAMETER"); // Append any type of state/params you would like
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Sorry, something went wrong");
  }
})

...

app.get('/callback', async function(req, res) {
  let url = redirectUri + req.originalUrl;

  console.log('req.query: ', req.query) // this will the the same state/params you passed to the API

  // ...do api stuff..
  // ref: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node-oauth2-app

  res.send(req.query);
})
```

https://github.com/SerKnight/xero-node-basic-app/blob/master/index.js#L37

*Worth noting that the optional `state:` param of the XeroClient is reserved for openidclient stuff.. Don't use it. just append it to the consent url.*

Comment: sorry I should have clarified, yes I am trying to get the state code back with the callback to identify the user

Comment: Is it blowing up? I believe I fixed this way back in this commit: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/commit/62408551d35a75eb3630a5aef2cb529c9623c4c7#diff-feeb9bb1ac85af27d17bd54b75fc7285R11 What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using v4.0.7 of `xero-node`

Comment: It is not blowing up, it is just that I am not getting the same state code back on the callback. There is a `session_state` parameter but it comes back as a completely different code to the one I supplied

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the purpose/use case for this state code...but my understanding was that it is there to validate that the callback is from the same user - i.e. I can parse it as a query param from the callback url and compare it with when I have stored locally to validate the user's "session" so to speak.

Comment: So instead of passing state to the xero client, just append it to the authentication url! Thanks for your question - hopefully other folks can use this too :)